# Is the maven surefire plugin needed to run unit tests?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

Is the maven surefire plugin needed to run unit tests when using the `mvn clean test` command?

I read the documentation and know it says that:

> The Surefire Plugin is used during the test phase of the build
>   lifecycle to execute the unit tests of an application. It generates
>   reports in two different file formats:
>
> Plain text files (*.txt) XML files (*.xml) By default, these files are
>   generated at ${basedir}/target/surefire-reports.

However, I ran the tests without using the surefire plugin and they all passed.

Comment: You can use other plugins, but it is used and bound by default. You can look at `mvn help:effective-pom` to the the plugins which are inherited from the standard pom parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no not **needed** but it is **used** by maven per default. if you have a better plugin you can change it. but i would prefer the defaults.

the maven-surfire-plugin is bound to the test phase of the default lifecycle. the maven-surfire-plugins runs all Tests matches the filename pattern **Test*.java, *Test.java und *TestCase.java** reside in the directory **src/test/java**.

for more information have a look at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

you can verify this on the console output... here is the tailed output of **mvn test**...:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rechnungsverwaltung ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ rechnungsverwaltung ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.447 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-17T22:36:59+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hava a look at the line. there you can see that the maven-surefire-plugin is used

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @
```